# Mouse clicMouse click drags and only releases with a click of the left button (Intermittent)

Tags: mouse, xfce, drag-and-drop, click-policy

So every couple days or so my external usb wireless mouse decides to start dragging things around.  The only symptom is click and hold of the left mouse button.  Motion works find as does using that mouse buttons.  Sometimes it holds a click that I make and other times it’s like it grabs objects as I pass the cursor over them.  It will drag tabs in libreOffice, files in Thunar, and links in Tomtom.  Pretty much anything that can be dragged.  Sometimes it will draw the selection rectangle on the desktop.  Without exception a subsequent left mouse click will release the drag, but once the mouse has gotten in this mood it continues to do this every few seconds.  It seems to only be the external mouse that is afflicted.  The touch pad on the laptop does not seem to have this although I pretty much never use the touch pad so I can’t be certain of this.

Models and versions:

- laptop   lenovo U430
- Mouse #1 Logitech M305
- Mouse #2 Logitech M305
- Ubuntu 14.04 GNOME and Ubuntu 16.04 XFCE

What I’ve tried:

1. a fresh boot seems to give me a couple days of peace, but it does
   return.
2. I swapped mouse #1 for #2 no change. Although both mice
   are the same exact model.
3. I setup another bootable partition and
   tried a newer Ubuntu release and even a different window manager as
   you see listed above.

Any ideas that don’t involve reinventing the wheel or compiling custom drivers that will break every-other time I update Ubuntu?

Comment: Try using another mouse on the system or using it on another system to make sure the mouse is not the problem,

Comment: As mentioned in my OP.  I have tried that.